# Mostrar arrays con ForEach en elementos HTML

Tags: javascript, html, script

Tengo un script y necesito mostrar el resultado en un `<td id="nombre"></td> | <td id="valor"></td>`. Tengo lo siguiente:

**HTML:**

```
<p id="entrada" style="display:none;">
Cowbell 210 gp
    5 gp
Empty Potion Flask (Medium) 5 gp
Empty Potion Flask (Large)  5 gp
Execowtioner Mask   240 gp
Giant Pacifier  170 gp
Glob of Glooth  125 gp
Glooth Injection Tube   350 gp
</p>

<td id="nombre"></td> | <td id="valor"></td>
```

**Javascript:**

```
let nombreValorList = document.getElementById("entrada").innerHTML.split(/\n/).filter(n => n);
const nombreRE = /[a-z ]+/i; //letras y espacios
const cantidadesRE = /[0-9]* ?[0-9]+/ //numeros
let nombres = nombreValorList.map(nv => {
  if (nv){
   const r= nv.match(nombreRE)[0].trim();
   return r
  }
});

let precios = nombreValorList.map(nv => {
  if (nv){
   const r= nv.match(cantidadesRE)[0].replace(/ /g,'');
   return r
  }
});

nombres.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + '-</div>'));

precios.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + ' gp' + '-</div>'));
```

He tratado de cambiar:

```
nombres.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + '-</div>'));
precios.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element + ' gp' + '-</div>'));
```

por:

```
document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML
document.getElementById("valor").innerHTML
```

Y no me ha funcionado. Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la variable element agrégale el .val()

`nombres.forEach(element => document.write('<div>-' + element.val() + '-</div>'));`
 o pone `debugger` dentro del foreach para conocer si tiene datos o de que forma lo esta recibiendo dentro. Saludos